# SSRS Reporting - How do you prevent a page break before a row in a Tablix?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, row, ssrs-tablix, page-break

I have a tablix that contains a fair bit of verbiage. There are other tablix that contain a user defined amount of information. The tablix that contains the large amount of verbiage comes afterwards. Upon printing the report, the row of the tablix that contains the large amount of verbiage will push to the next page every time. I am looking to prevent this from happening.

I am not using Row Groups.

I have set the Page break options to Keep together on one possible checked and unchecked.

Comment: Is there any space on design view beyond the limits of the tablix you've designed?  Try to eliminate any extraneous blank areas and shrink your margins to try to get more room.  It's really just a matter of making it fit better.  It may look like it fits in design view, but you'll probably have to do something to make the report squeeze into a slightly smaller space.

Comment: I see what you mean. There isn't any excess space between the header of the tablix and the row of the tablix. It isn't necessarily about the spacing here. It's that the row will push to the second page if from it's current page it would extend to the second. I want the row to be able to fall onto more than one page if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found putting the tablix inside a text box helps control this. See below:

[image]

Another thing that helps is applying filters to the row to handle how many results are displayed. See below:

[image]

This should prevent the page over flowing onto the next. To fit as much data as possible on the page you can always change font size or squeeze everything closer together.

Hope this helps.

Thanks 
Gav

Comment: Let me try and phrase this differently. I have 72 lines in a single "row" in my tablix. SSRS wants to keep the 72 lines together because it is a single row. What I am looking for is to have the 72 lines have the ability to split when it needs to. In the sense that there would be 24 lines on one page and 48 lines one the second page. Given that these lines are all in one row, it is not working the way that I am expecting it to. I haven't found a solution for this yet

Comment: Wow all those lines in a single row? Can you edit the question and provide a screenshot of what you have currently so It's easier to understand. Thanks Gav

Comment: Provide screenshots what you see before and after the report is ran. Thanks Gav

Comment: I ended up creating separate rows in the tablix to account for this. This is a sufficient solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem at all. Thanks Gav